# Get Application Directory on MacOS return path with appName.app/Contents/MacOS

Tags: macos, qt, file

I am building a cross-platform app that creates a file for the user.
To get the file's full path I wrote the following code:

```
QString fullPath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath();
fullPath.append("/").append(filename);
```

After searching for the file, I found in the debugger that my file exists under `<myAppName>.app/Contents/MacOS`.

The user does not have a way to get those file (except via the terminal).

**The question:** What should I do to receive "normal" path ?

- I do not want use substring functions because same code should work well on Linux and Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally asked the question in Qt forum [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/58325-Get-Application-Directory-on-MacOS-return-path-with-appName-app-Contents-MacOS?p=260028#post260028) and the answer I got is:

I cannot create files there (app directory) because normal users don't have permissions for that.  `QStandardPaths` can be used as a solutions for the above issue.